# kableExtra won't compile with full_width and XeLaTeX

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex, kable, xelatex

Having `full_width = T` in my kable function results in the error:

```
    ! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
\tabu@elapsedtime ...optime {\the \pdfelapsedtime 
                                                  }\tabu@message {(tabu)\tab...
```

But removing `- \usepackage{fontspec}` and `latex_engine: xelatex` from the YAML allows it to work.

Reproducible code:

````
---
title: "For Stackoverflow"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
---


```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library(kableExtra)

data <- data.frame('Column 1'=c('1','2','3','4','5'), 'Column 2'=c('a','b','c', 'd', 'e'))

kable(data, 'latex') %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = T)

```
````

Here is the tex file:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(kableExtra)}

\NormalTok{data <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{data.frame}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{'Column 1'}\NormalTok{=}\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{'1'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'2'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'3'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'4'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'5'}\NormalTok{), }\StringTok{'Column 2'}\NormalTok{=}\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{'a'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'b'}\NormalTok{,}\StringTok{'c'}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{'d'}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{'e'}\NormalTok{))}

\KeywordTok{kable}\NormalTok{(data, }\StringTok{'latex'}\NormalTok{) }\OperatorTok{%>%}
\StringTok{  }\KeywordTok{kable_styling}\NormalTok{(}\DataTypeTok{full_width =}\NormalTok{ T)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}X}


\hline
Column.1 & Column.2\\
\hline
1 & a\\
\hline
2 & b\\
\hline
3 & c\\
\hline
4 & d\\
\hline
5 & e\\
\hline
\end{tabu}



\end{document}
```

It looks like the main difference between the tex files of `full_width=T` and `full_width=F` is that when true, tabu is used; while when false, tabular is used.

Here is my session info:

```
- Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                                    
 date     2020-02-20                  

- Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ! package              * version    date       lib source                               
   assertthat             0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   backports              1.1.4      2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   boot                   1.3-22     2019-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   broom                  0.5.2      2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   callr                  3.2.0      2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   cellranger             1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   cli                    1.1.0      2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   codetools              0.2-16     2018-12-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   colorspace             1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   crayon                 1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   curl                   3.3        2019-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   data.table             1.12.2     2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   DBI                    1.0.0      2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   desc                   1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   devtools               2.2.1      2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   digest                 0.6.19     2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   dplyr                * 0.8.1      2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   ellipsis               0.3.0      2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                       
   evaluate               0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   forcats              * 0.4.0      2019-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   foreach                1.4.4      2017-12-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   formatR                1.6        2019-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   fs                     1.3.1      2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   futile.logger          1.4.3      2016-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   futile.matrix          1.2.7      2018-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   futile.options         1.0.1      2018-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                                                    
   generics               0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   ggplot2              * 3.1.1      2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   glue                   1.3.1      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   gtable                 0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   haven                  2.1.0      2019-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   hms                    0.4.2      2018-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   htmltools              0.3.6      2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   httr                   1.4.0      2018-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   iterators              1.0.10     2018-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   jsonlite               1.6        2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   kableExtra           * 1.1.0.9000 2019-11-05 [1] Github (haozhu233/kableExtra@a9504c0)
   knitr                * 1.25       2019-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                       
   lambda.r               1.2.3      2018-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   lambda.tools           1.0.9      2016-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   lattice                0.20-38    2018-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   lazyeval               0.2.2      2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   lpSolve                5.6.13     2015-09-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   lubridate              1.7.4      2018-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   magrittr               1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   memoise                1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   modelr                 0.1.4      2019-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   munsell                0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   nlme                   3.1-139    2019-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   numDeriv               2016.8-1   2016-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   PerformanceAnalytics   1.5.2      2018-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   pillar                 1.4.0      2019-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   pkgbuild               1.0.3      2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   pkgconfig              2.0.2      2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   pkgload                1.0.2      2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   plyr                   1.8.4      2016-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                                                 
   pracma                 2.2.5      2019-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   prettyunits            1.0.2      2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
 D processx               3.3.1      2019-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   ps                     1.3.0      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   purrr                * 0.3.2      2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   quadprog               1.5-7      2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   quantmod               0.4-14     2019-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   R.methodsS3            1.7.1      2016-02-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   R.oo                   1.22.0     2018-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   R6                     2.4.0      2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   Rcpp                   1.0.1      2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   readr                * 1.3.1      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   readxl                 1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   registry               0.5-1      2019-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   remotes                2.1.0      2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                       
   reshape2               1.4.3      2017-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   rlang                  0.3.4      2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   rmarkdown            * 1.12       2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   RMTstat                0.3        2014-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   RODBC                  1.3-15     2017-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   ROI                    0.3-2      2019-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   RPostgreSQL            0.6-2      2017-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   rprojroot              1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   rstudioapi             0.10       2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   rvest                  0.3.4      2019-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   scales                 1.0.0      2018-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   sessioninfo            1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   slam                   0.1-45     2019-02-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   stringi                1.4.3      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   stringr              * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tawny                  2.1.7      2018-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tawny.types            1.1.5      2018-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   testthat             * 2.1.1      2019-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tibble               * 2.1.1      2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tidyr                * 0.8.3      2019-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tidyselect             0.2.5      2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tidyverse            * 1.2.1      2017-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   tinytex              * 0.17       2019-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                       
   TTR                    0.23-4     2018-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   usethis                1.5.0      2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   viridisLite            0.3.0      2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   webshot                0.5.1.9001 2019-09-25 [1] Github (wch/webshot@4bbf4f7)         
   withr                  2.1.2      2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   xfun                   0.11       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   XML                    3.98-1.19  2019-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   xml2                   1.2.0      2018-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   xts                    0.11-2     2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   yaml                   2.2.0      2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                       
   zoo                  * 1.8-5      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does it compile with lualatex? I believe that the default is pdflatex, so when you remove the line to use xelatex, pdflatex is used.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this issue, my setup => R version 3.6.2 | x86_64-pc-linux-gnu | Debian 10.

Comment: Yes it does compile with lualatex as well. Xelatex is chosen for the fontspec package and calibri font.

Comment: ah, I see. I didn't realize that you need to use xelatex to work with fontspec and calibri. thank you.

Comment: Actually, fontspec and calibri do work with lualatex. I thought xelatex was chosen for that reason, but testing it now it doesn't seem so. I'm researching different tradeoffs between the two, but I'm not seeing a change at all in my report by using lualatex rather than xelatex.